# How to handle "dparser" exception which stops the program in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, date-parsing

I have the following code which should not stop my program I guess:

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

t = "79999999999"

try:                
    dp = dparser.parse(t, fuzzy=True)
except ValueError as ve:
    print('ValueError: {}'.format(ve))
    dp = None
```

but the error is

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long.

How to handle this error or rather how to continue and handle any error? Why it's not working for this particular case while many exceptions are skipped?

**EDIT**

I've found:

```
except:
    pass
```

skips it but no message can be shown. It's ok but how to have message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple exceptions as tuple.

**Ex:**

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser

t = "79999999999"

try:                
    dp = dparser.parse(t, fuzzy=True)
except (ValueError, OverflowError) as e:   #OR except Exception as e:
    print('Error: {}'.format(e))
    dp = None
```

Comment: Ok this works but will it be ok if I add at the end: `finally:    pass` ?

Comment: Instead you can use `except Exception as e:` it will catch all errors and your code will not break

Comment: @Rakesh Your solution isn't recommended. Each exception should be handled separately, otherwise, likely to miss exceptions that need to be fixed.